# MicrosoftReportViewer (VS 2008)

Tags: vb.net

Im using VB 2008 Express edition and it doesn't have ReportViewer installed and I believe Express Eds doesn't have that.

Is there anyway to add the ReportViewer in Toolbox?

I tried downloading this Microsoft Report Viewer Redistributable 2008 but I'm not sure if i'm doing the right thing. Still there's no ReportViewer in my VB Express 2008. Or you should manually add it? If so then how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have to use VB 2008 Express? From (I think) 2012 they have had a free Community Edition, which is pretty much Pro but for free.  Any reason not to use VS 2017 Community Edition?

Comment: That said, if you have downloaded and installed a version of the `ReportViewer` control that is compatible, you would add it to the Toolbox like you would any other control, which starts with a right-click on the Toolbox itself.